# Managing FCM device groups server side

Tags: node.js, firebase-admin

I am looking for a way to manage FCM device groups server side, hopefully with the use of the node.js [`firebase-admin`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node) library. As far as I can see the only way of achieving this is by using the old GCM based rest-endpoint [`POST: https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group#managing_device_groups)

However I do not feel confident using that as [using the gcm system is discouraged](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq).

I have searched through the github repo and cound not seem to find anything on `Device Groups` anywhere. Is this feature something which isn't supposed to be used anymore? Or is it perhaps not documented, or been overlooked, for some reason?

I am aware that creating device groups is achievable on the client side, but it does seem to require the user to have a google account, which unfortunately in my case I cannot assume.

From https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group#managing_device_groups

> To create a device group on the client, the device must have at least one Google account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been in contact with Google about this. They say that using the GCM api is the current preferred way. For my project I made a simple server-side wrapper library around their api so I could make things a bit easier for myself.

---

EDIT:

FCM has now added support for device groups; https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group